# NSolve: Mathematica 9 issue

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

In *Mathematica* 8 the following expression evaluates and returns a result in terms of `InverseFunction`:

```
NSolve[Integrate[x^(1/2)/(Exp[x - μ] - 1), {x, 0, ∞}] == C, μ]
```

where `C` is a constant. But in *Mathematica* 9 the expression does not evaluate:

> NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. [>>](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html)

Is this a bug, a regression, or a feature? And how can this equation can be solved in V9?

Particular, trying to solve this:

```
NSolve[PolyLog[3/2, 20 x] == 2, x]
```

In *Mathematica* 8 and *Mathematica* 9 gives different results:

[*Mathematica* 8 (correct result)](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7qoq8dv0jms6cja/nsolve-polylog-8.nb?dl=1):

```
NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
{{x -> 0.05 InverseFunction[PolyLog, 2, 2][3/2, 
 2.0000000000000000000000000000000]}}
```

[*Mathematica* 9](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzxd5mf5mkdflj3/nsolve-polylog-9.nb):

```
NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. >>
NSolve[PolyLog[3/2, 20 x] == 2, x]
```

---

**UPD:** That's a confirmed bug with `NSolve`, that I already reported to developers of Wolfram Mathematica long time ago.

Comment: With `eqn = Integrate[x^(1/2)/( Exp[x - \[Mu]] - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}]` it looks like `eqn` is always positive so the equation has no solution.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: True. Original there was a bunch of user constants. Just a mistyped after `==` sign.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in V10 (although the output is now in terms of  `Root` instead of `InverseFunction`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general for a non-polynomial equation you can use `FindRoot` to solve it :

```
eqn[m_] = Integrate[x^(1/2)/( Exp[x - m] - 1), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] ;

(* using 2 initial values for the solver *)
roots[r_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[eqn[m] == r, {m, -1.23, -0.456}][[1, 2]]
```

Check :

```
dataRoots = {roots[#], #} & /@ Range[0.1, 2, 0.1];

Show[ListPlot[dataRoots, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}, 
           GridLines -> Transpose[dataRoots], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
     Plot[eqn[m], {m, -10, 0}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]